# Magento 2 installation error [--search-engine]

Tags: magento2, error, installation, elasticsearch, docker

I am installing magento 2.3.4-P2 in a docker container and I am getting this error "The --search-engine option does not exist" when executing the installation command with elasticsearch options

--search-engine="elasticsearch7" --elasticsearch-host="elasticsearc" --elasticsearch-port="9200"

[image]

Comment: In case it's due to a docker miss ; Check the result of the command directly in the container if you have access to it : bin/magento setup:install --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch --elasticsearch-port=9200

Comment: I am executing directly in the container